# Does Colt provide "d-dimensional" matrices?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, colt

Colt library is pretending to provide "Dense and sparse fixed sized (non-resizable) 1,2, 3 and d-dimensional matrices" (Section [Features / Templated Multidimensional matrices](http://acs.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/)).

But in API itself I see no any implementation, higher than 3: http://acs.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/package-summary.html

Please cure my tired eyes :)

Comment: What is "d"? n-dimensional? Couldn't you just consolidate multiple matrices into a custom class?

Comment: Colt does obviously not support it, and I'm not aware of any library that can do this. (In fact: Even 3D is already rather unusual). Do you really need this as a *Matrix* including multiplication and other operations, or do you just need an "n-dimensional array"? (BTW: The Colt 3D matrices don't support many operations either...)

Comment: The question is just about matching between claims and reality. Actually I need tensors.